# Why does my reducer does not display its value in a component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-reducers, redux-actions

I have a React.js app where I use `Redux`. I have an action which is supposed to set a value in the reducer's state but it seems like it does not work. I used `console.log()` to display the `action.payload` of the action in the reducer and it seems to be received but when I call the reducer in the component where I need it, it does not show.

Here is my code:

Action:

```
   export const setModeWarning = (warning) => ({
     type: 'MQTT:SET_MODE_WARNING',
     payload:  warning
   });
```

Reducer:

```
case 'MQTT:SET_MODE_WARNING':
        console.log("ENTERED")
        console.log(action.payload)
        console.log(initialState.modeWarning)
        return {
            ...state,
            modeWarning:action.payload.warning,
      
        }
```

Component:

```
   const {modeWarning} = this.props
    console.log("MODE WARNING")
    console.log(modeWarning)

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        reconnect:  state.reconnect,
        battery : state.battery,
        mode: state.mode,
        modeMessage:state.modeMessage,
        messageWarning:state.messageWarning,
        updateMessage:state.updateMessage,
        modeWarning:state.modeWarning
    }
  }

  
export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(InformationScreen)
```

Comment: How are you dispatching the action in the component ? Also check in the redux dev tools .

Comment: I added this now in the question @Shyam

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the action payload matches the reducer payload

action `payload: warning`

reducer `modeWarning: action.payload // no .warning`

or

action `payload: { warning }`

reducer `modeWarning: action.payload.warning`

Comment: I did this, but no change.